# MongoDB. [Key Too Large To Index]

Tags: mongodb, indexing, full-text-search

**Some Background:** I'm planning to use MongoDB as the publishing frontend db for a few of my websites. The actual data will be kept in a SQL Server db and there will be background jobs that will populate the MongoDB at predefined time intervals for readonly purposes to boost website performance.

**The Situation:** I have a table 'x' that i translated into a mongo collection, everything worked fine.

'x' has a column 'c' that was originally a NVARCHAR(MAX) in the source db and has multilingual text in it.

When I was searching by column 'c', mongo was doing fullscan on the collection.

So I tried doing an ensureIndex({c : 1 }) which worked but when I checked the mongodb logs it showed me that 90% of the data could not be indexed as [Key Too Large To Index] !!

And thus is has indexed 10% of the data and now **only** returns results from that 10% !!

What are my alternatives ??

**Note:** I was using this column to do full text searching in SQL Server, now im not sure if I should go ahead with Mongo or not :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to search text inside a large string you can use one of those:
[keyword splitting](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo)
[regular expression](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions)

the former has the downside that you need some "logic" to combine the keyword to make a search, the latter heavily impacts on performance.
probably if you really need full text search the best option is to use an external indexer like solr or lucene.

Answer (score 24):

Try to run your mongod process with this parameter:

```
sudo mongod --setParameter failIndexKeyTooLong=false
```

And than try again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can do some elaboration, you could extract some key words and put them in a field:

```
   _keywords : [ "mongodb" , "full search" , "nosql" ]
```

and make an index on that.

Comment: Interesting, so that means I can use something like lucene to breakup the text into keywords and put them in an array field and index that field?

Comment: yes, but if put _all_ the words in the array field you will face the same problem

Answer (score 0):

### Don't use mongo for full text searching

its not designed for that. Yes obviously you will get an error **key too large on indexing** for long string values.

Better approach would be using full text search servers (solr/lucene or sphinx) if your main concern is search.

Answer (score 0):

Recent (**2.4 and above**) MongoDB builds provide a couple other options:

1. As the OP's stated desire is for full text search, the right approach would be to use a [`text` index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) which directly supports that use case.
2. For an exact match index on long string values you can use a [`hashed` index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-hashed/).